# Ionic IOS Camera permission still denied after set usage description in config.xml

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, config

I would like to ask that why i still does not have camera permission for ios device when i already set NSCameraUsageDescription in the config xml. Below attachment photo is the error i got when i run the camera function. Before that, the config.xml is hidden for me which i use , `ionic integrations enable cordova --add` to enable it and configure it.

```
   <platform name="ios">
       <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
       <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
       <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
           <string>You can take photos</string>
       </config-file>
       <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
       <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
       <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
       <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
       <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
       <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
       <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
       <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
       <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
       <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
       <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
       <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
       <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
       <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
       <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
       <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
       <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
       <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
       <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
       <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
       <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
       <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
       <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
       <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
       <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
       <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
       <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
       <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
       <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
       <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
       <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
       <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
       <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
       <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
       <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
       <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
       <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
       <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
       <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
       <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
       <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
       <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
       <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
       <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
       <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
   </platform>
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
</widget>
```

[xCode Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydpsL.png)

[Config xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLfI9.png)

Comment: add camera permission in `info.plist` file in xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Cordova CLI 6.5.0 you can write in the info.plist directly by using the `edit-config` tag in the config.xml like this:

```
<platform name="ios">

 <edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" overwrite="true">
      <string>YOUR-PERMISSION-REQUEST</string>
 </edit-config>
 <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" overwrite="true" >
      <string>YOUR-PERMISSION-REQUEST</string>
 </edit-config>
 <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" overwrite="true">
      <string>YOUR-PERMISSION-REQUEST</string>
 </edit-config>
</platform>
```

and make sure you are using latest version of the plugins or values might be overwritten by the plugin variables.

Comment: Appreaciate for the suggestion, I will marked this as the solution for the problem

Comment: @Louay Sleman - For my iOS app, I have my config.xml using `<config-file ...>` with custom permission messages as per the instructions in `cordova.plugins.diagnostics` - but when I compile my app from cli: `ionic cordova build ios` the final `*-Info.plist` doesn't show my custom messages, it shows the plugins default/generic messages.  Any idea on how to fix this so its properly using the config.xml defined permissions messages?

Comment: Well, I changed the `config-file` to `edit-config` syntax and now its putting the correct permission messages back in my Info.plist file.  Not certain why the original suddenly stopped working and was being over written by the plugin's defaults.

Comment: And for Xcode13 you directly go into Xcode, and go to the app detail info tab and click the add button to create the new permission requirement.